# How to make reasonably sized gifs in Linux?

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have a bunch of shots from a Raspberry Pi webcam, that I want to combine into a gif. They're 640x480 pixel jpg files, about 200 kB each. I have 200 of them I'd like to combine.

Right now, if I do `convert -loop 0 *.jpg out.gif`, it ends up being like 45 MB, which is crazy.

I can do a few tricks, like adding the options: `-layers optimizeframe`, `-colors 40`, `-dither None`, and `-fuzz 20%`, which gets it down to 13 MB, which is still pretty horrendous.

I know I can use the `-resize` option; doing `resize 50%` gets it down to ~5 MB, but that's still kind of large and it's now a 320x240 image of fairly low quality (due to the fuzz/colors arguments).

I'm pretty sure I've seen gifs on the internet before that weren't this huge in file size, but were large images and pretty good quality. Is there something else to try? are they actually getting a lot more compression from using .gifv's or something? Or are they usually not 200 frames? (I feel like I've seen ones that were long enough and must have been a high enough frame rate that they were.)

To be honest, I don't specifically need them to be gif's, but I want something that just auto plays in a browser, without any special plugins. The other thing is, I **want it to be playing automatically and loop like a gif**. I'm looking at just making an mp4 with ffmpeg, but I don't see how to make it get treated as a gifv or whatever and play/loop automatically.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your problem, however yea the gifs you typically see are usually not 200 frames if they are light weight

Comment: To reduce your GIFs further there are two other things to do. 1) Use one of the non-imagemagick gif tools to optimize them better. see https://imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#gif_non-im. 2) Use one common color map for all the frames by using -remap with a single colormap image. You can select a few frames from the full length of the sequence, append them, then reduce the colors to 256 and get the unique colors and make that into a color map. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#extract.  See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap, but use -dither none.

Comment: CONTINUED: See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/video/ for an example of using a common color map, but it that case they are starting with a video and converting to an animated gif.

Answer (score 0):

To make GIF in Linux, you need to install ImageMagick. If you use any Debian based distro like Linux Mint, Ubuntu or elementary OS, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

If you use any other distro, find this app in your package manager. After that, place all the images you want to create a GIF from in one folder. I put these images in the gif-icons folder.

Comment: did you read my post at all? I'm already using `convert` which is part of imagemagick, and my question was about how to use it in a specific way.